# Read first n lines of an RDS file in R using readRDS()

Tags: r

I am trying to read the "counties.rds" file which contains US consensus data for counties. The only problem is that I do not need all data and I'd rather read the first n lines of such a file.

I took a look at the readRDS documentation and could not find any argument or parameter for such purpose and only found the following:

```
readRDS(file, refhook = NULL)
```

I am wondering if such a thing exists.

Comment: Just roughly apropos, maybe of some help: [A list of pages/articles/slides on handling spatial data, @gis.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45327/tutorials-to-handle-spatial-data-in-r).